# Leaky Sun Roof (Moon Roof) 2012 Ford Focus SEL hatchback

Tags: ford, focus, water-leak, sunroof

I've been told it might be "drainage tubes," but I don't know where they are or what to look for. The car was parked under a tree for a while, and there was debris under the hood, so maybe debris got in the moon roof?

Where are the tubes, what do they look like, and what can I do to clean them out?

Last year, the rain leaked in every time it rained and fried all the interior lights above and may still be causing the battery to drain; I constantly need a jump start/NocoBoost. I also had to scoop out all the water from the floor, like it was a sinking ship.
The sun roof/ moon roof still operates, surprisingly so.
Thank you for your help.